# How to change bg of a table row, selected by its attribute value?

Tags: javascript, html

I've an HTML table with where each row has a unique attribute. I want to change the bg of a row when the user selects its unique id in a form text field.

It has to be js, I don't want the form to post.

Thanks

Comment: Would be easier to answer seeing your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should suit you: http://jsfiddle.net/fFApC/

Leave a comment if you need clarification/code update.

Answer (score 1):

Although some of your HTML code would be appreciated, here is a basic implementation.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var attributeToSearch = $('.search').val();
    $('table tr[uniqueAttribute="' + attribute + '"]').css('background', 'red');
});
```

The HTML is supposed to be like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr uniqueAttribute="foo">...</tr>
        <tr uniqueAttribute="bar">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the form:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="search" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

On form submit we check the input the user entered and search for the table row which has that attribute value and change its background.